# Schengen Visa 90/180 rule with intermittent work-permit from Sweden

Tags: schengen, sweden, 90-180-visa-rules, work-permit

I am a Indian passport holder with a Schengen Visa (type C, valid from May'18 to May'19, 90 days stay). I'm in Sweden since May'18 (till Nov'18) with a Schengen visa and I also have a Swedish work-permit (valid from July'18 to Jan'19).

Now I am traveling back to India (in Nov'18), but what about the validity of my Schengen Visa with regard to the 90/180 rule?

Can I travel in other Schengen countries until visa is valid ?

Comment: You can only have one status at a time and to switch to another status you either need to exit the Schengen area and reenter with the new one, or apply for a change at the immigration offices.

Comment: @MusoniusRufus whether it is  necessary to leave and reenter is oddly enough specified by national law.

Comment: Thanks All.
@HonoraryWorldCitizen, I am not sure it's mandatory to exit and re-enter in this case as I entered using Schengen visa and later on received my work-permit while in Schengen only.

Comment: @SarjitS Isn’t receiving the work permit essentially the same as changing status through immigration offices? In the USA that’s what it’s called.

Comment: @Jacob, in this case my Schengen visa shouldn't be taken in account (during valid work-permit) then.

I will check and confirm with the immigration officer.